# '?' not working in C Posix regular expressions

Tags: c, regex

I am trying to extract a string within double quotes in C. For example:

```
String[100] = "Hi,\"This is awesome\" and \"So is this\""
```

I only need to find the first match, "This is awesome". And this is what I tried,

```
regcomp(&preg, "\"(.*?)\"", REG_EXTENDED);
regexec(&preg, String, 2, regm, 0);
```

where regm is the match array.

Instead of `"This is awesome"`, I get `"This is awesome" and "So is this"` as the match.

Shouldn't the `?` in `(.*?)` limit the reg exp to finding the first match?

Comment: Can you post your code more clearly

Answer (score 5):

No. Apparently this `.*?` thing you've written is intended to be a "non-greedy repetition" and came from Perl or some other language (not sure which). It has no such special meaning in POSIX ERE; the `?` is just redundant. Instead try the correct form: `"\"([^\"]*)\""`

The specification for POSIX ERE can be found here:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04

Comment: Thank you :) Can you point me to any link which explains the capabilities of the posix regex? I am not sure whether what I am looking at is correct. I am trying to find out the equivalent of 'negative look behind' in C posix reg exp but have been unsuccessful so far.

Comment: Added a link to spec.

Comment: Note that POSIX ERE lacks anything resembling look-behind or look-ahead assertions and most other Perl-ish features. You can emulate some of them by using a longer regex with a parenthesized subexpression for the actual capture, but if you find you really want to do Perl RE's, it might make sense to use a library that provides Perl-compatible RE. The original PCRE is a bad implementation (pathologically bad performance on many RE's) but I believe the Google re2 library provides a good PCRE implementation.

Comment: Thank you for the link :) I looked into PCRE. It does what I want but am not allowed to use it. I am currently trying to accomplish this, "if there is a \ character before the ", do not match that double quote and continue to find the next double quote".

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://cwestblog.com/2013/02/15/regular-expression-match-a-string-literal/

Comment: If this is homework or some other kind of assignment/challenge-problem, are you use regex is even the right tool? This is starting to sound like an XY problem.